# Controlling your printer with .ps files

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, postscript

I am trying to construct a laser cutter and I have chosen the motor mechanism from an old inkjet printer to be my X axis. I have also been wondering if I can control it via `.ps` scripts. Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does PS mean PostScript, PhotoShop or Powershell?

Comment: ps = postscript

Comment: Yes, you can control PS printers with PS snippets. They are normally used to add extra controls to a PS driver. For example, I have created a snippet to override the driver's minimum line thickness. However, inkjet printers do not understand PS, so I can't see how you would make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High quality ink-jet printers support PostScript. Unfortunately they use PostScript to render raster images. The motors are controlled by firmware. It moves the head back and forth to print raster images generated by PostScript code. So there is no easy way to control printer's motors or other hardware from a PostScript program.

PostScript has access to the file system. If printer's OS provides access to motor controllers via file system and security system allows writing to the files from the PostScript interpreter, then it is possible.